# Google Spreadsheet - populate row from drop down item

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a Google Docs spreadsheet, its for my brothers construction company. Its to assist him with quotes for potential jobs, so he can get control of costs..

I have three sheets, Quote, Settings, Products.

Quote will contain the actual itemised quote. Settings will contain some static values like the VAT and Products contains the actual cost of products i.e Timber €49.00, Electrician €250.00 etc.

I've figured out how to create drop down boxes which contain the item code from the products sheet, but when I select the item code I want the entire row to be populated with the details from the products sheet.

Here's a link to what I have created so far:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AseLC0_NOCETdHRTV1Rlc3pGblEtTnBzQ1A2VDlEakE&usp=sharing

Any help appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: I tried to look at your sheet but it says that I need permission to access it.

Comment: Although, based on your description it seems like the solution is very simple -- just us the vlookup function. http://anandexcels.wordpress.com/tag/vlookup-function-in-google-docs/

Comment: @Stephen Sorry its public now.

Comment: @Stephen, I just figured it out from your link. If you make this an answer I'll accept it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to pull a row of data from another sheet is to use the vlookup function. The details can be found at: http://anandexcels.wordpress.com/tag/vlookup-function-in-google-docs/