# Display columns of information in Google Sheets based on Drop down selection

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

What I am looking to do is have a list of items in a dropdown list in cell A1. Lets say the list is "Presidents, Movie Stars, Rappers".

When I select Presidents I want Column B in Sheet 1 to list all the presidents with column C listing their party they represented and column D to list their years in office. When I select Movie stars I want column B to List various Movie Star names, Column C to list number of movies starred in and Column D to display their highest paid film.

So in short I want 1 dropdown to populate 3 columns worth of data.

Everything I have looked up uses scripts(which I think this is completely doable without using) uses VLOOKUP but has 1 cell worth of data appear(ex, A1 dropdown displays data in A2 but not data in B1:B50, C1:C50, and D1:D50) or doesnt worth with multiple columns of data. I am fine if the data pulls from another sheet I just think there is a better way to do this then filling in 200+ cells with an if:then function based on my selection in cell A1. Anyone know an easy way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheet - populate row from drop down item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944720/google-spreadsheet-populate-row-from-drop-down-item)

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution, in my opinion, is to do something like the following:

1. Create a column (which you can later hide) that has all value combinations, with a delimiter between the values. For example, you could have "Presidents>Barack Obama>Democrat>2008-2016"
2. Then create a simple function (no VLOOKUP needed!) to pull the individual values by using FIND to findn the location of the delimiters and split the combination.